# Sass get sibling hover state for dropdown menu

Tags: sass, dropdown

I'm trying to build a fairly simple Sass mixin for a dropdown menu built as an html list

My html is

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="name">My Name</div>
   <ul>
     <li>profile</li>
     <li>logout</li>
</div>
```

then I have a mixin which is applied to the UL

```
@mixin dropdown() {
  // create a dropdown list from a ul

  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  &:hover {
    display: block;
  }
  li {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
  li a {
    @include button();
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Then I am trying to simply make the css by including the mixin in the parent

```
.parent {
        position: relative;
        ul {
            @include dropdown();
        }
        &:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the mixin needs to set `ul { display:block}` when I hover on the parent so the css needs to read `.parent:hover ul {displa:block}` but of course, I'd prefer to have it assigned to the parent rather than add the class on the parent itself.

I thought I should be able to do `* &:hover` or `.parent:hover &` or something of that sort, but any combination I've tried has not worked.

Using `.parent:hover &` creates css of

```
header .parent ul:hover, .parent:hover header .parent ul {
        display: block; }
```

Which is not right.

Suggestions? Without having to specify the parent element would be preferred.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're using this mixin.  All you're showing are bits and pieces of code, nothing that actually shows how you're generating the output.

Comment: my apologies @cimmanon you are correct, I left out that very important detail. I've updated, and think I have a solution, but somebody else may have something better.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was trying to put the mixin no the dropdown itself, but thanks to @cimmanon pointing out that I didn't include how I am using the mixin, I reconsidered the approach and have re-created the mixin to be applied to the parent, which works pretty well, but somebody may have a better way.

```
.parent {
    @include dropdown();
}

@mixin dropdown() {
  display: relative;
  // create a dropdown list from a ul
  &:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    &:hover {
      display: block;
    }
}
```